Two contradictory derivations of Killing equation
In David Tongs lecture notes he derives the Killing equation by showing that the charge $Q=\xi_\mu \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ is conserved
$$ 0=\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \partial_{\nu}\xi_\mu  +\xi_\mu \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2} .$$
However in my lecture we did an alternative derivation which is based on $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha$
$$0=\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}= \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \nabla_\nu\xi_\mu+\xi_\mu \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \nabla_\nu\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} $$ which also leads to the Killing equation. Which approach is wrong?

The 2nd equation is more generic, the first equation holds for geodesic fields $dx^{\mu}/d\tau$ in flat space-time only (in inertial coordinates)

The comment above is wrong. Both derivations are correct.

@Prahar how is this possible? If we look only at the first term we have completely different expressions.

Individual terms are not the same. The two terms put together are the same.

As an overall comment, I stress that conservation of $Q$ is valid for the Killing vector $\xi$ if the considered curve is a geodesic.
Let us come to the issue.
First of all, generally speaking,  the identity $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha\tag{0}$$ deserves several comments to be intepreted.
Consider a tensor field $\Xi = \Xi(p)$ and a curve $\gamma= \gamma(s)$. Can  the composition $\Xi(\gamma(t))$  be derived is $s$?  It should be the meaning of
$$\frac{d}{ds} \Xi(\gamma(s))\:.$$
The answer is NO without further information and this proves that Eq.(0) is dangerous to be used without comments.
That is because, unless $\Xi$ is a scalar field,  $$\Xi(\gamma(s+h)) \quad  and \quad \Xi(\gamma(s))$$ belong to different tensor spaces (constructed out of tangent spaces at different points on the manifold) and, cosequently,  their difference is not defined.
If an affine connection $\nabla$ is provided on the manifold, for instance the Levi-Civita one, and the action of $\nabla$ is extended to tensor fields, one can define $\frac{d}{ds}$ as follows.
Assuming that  $\Xi$  is not a scalar field,
$$\frac{d}{ds} \Xi(\gamma(s)) := \left(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \Xi\right)_{\gamma(s)}\:. \tag{1}$$
In terms of the abstract index notation, the found definition can be rephrased to
$$\frac{d}{ds} \Xi^A(\gamma(s)) = \dot{\gamma}^\mu \nabla_\mu \Xi^A. $$
REMARK. If $\Xi=f$ is a scalar field, the left hand side of (1) is already defined
$$\frac{d}{ds} f(\gamma(s)) = \dot{\gamma}^\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu}\quad \mbox{independently of the used local chart}$$
and the definition (1) is however consistent with this fact just because the coordinate expression of the covariant derivative of a scalar field is the standard gradient in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The considered computation  uses a scalar field
$Q$. That is the reason of the twice possible procedure.
Procedure 1
One can derive everything using Eq.(1) and the properties of $\nabla$ (the validity of the Leibniz rule in particular) which are valid independently of the tensor type of $\Xi$,  intepreting $\frac{d}{ds}$ as in (1). Using again  the abstract index notation:
$$ 0=\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\dot{\gamma}^\mu \dot{\gamma}^\nu\nabla_{\nu}\xi_\mu  +\xi_\mu \dot{\gamma}^\nu\nabla_\nu\dot{\gamma}^\mu. \tag{2}$$
However there is another more elementary approach.
Procedure 2
One fixes a precise coordinate patch and performs all computations in that coordinate patch, using the standard derivation in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, for any choice of the values of indices $A$, using standard calculus we have
$$\frac{d}{ds} \Xi^A(x^1(s),\ldots, x^n(s))
= \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{\partial \Xi^A}{\partial x^\mu}\:.$$
If $\Xi=f$ is a scalar field, this definition of $\frac{d}{ds}$ is the same as the one based on the covariant derivative.
This approach applied to the scalar field $Q$ leads to the former procedure  used in Tongs' textbook:
$$ 0=\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}\tau}= \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \partial_\mu Q=\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\nu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} \partial_{\nu}\xi_\mu  +\xi_\mu \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2} \tag{3}.$$
Here one can expand $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}$  in coordinates:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2} + 
\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \frac{d x^\alpha}{d\tau} \frac{d x^\beta}{d\tau}= \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau} \nabla_\nu \frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} =\left(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}\right)^\mu $$
that, inserted in (3) yields back (2).

Both approaches are fine.
In the first approach, the analysis is done at the coordinate/component level of the equations. Simply asking the question how does $Q$ very with $\tau$ if we write everything out in coordinates. All normal calculus rules apply in this case. To get back a covariant expression at the end, requires recognizing the component expression for the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu\xi_\nu$.
The second approach takes a more covariant approach. To formally make sense of what is being done here requires the introduction of some additional technology, namely the notion of a geodesic congruence, a collection of geodesics covering a neighborhood such that its tangents form a vector field $u^\mu$. By defining $Q$ on a geodesic congruence, $Q$ is an actual scalar field, and we can ask whether it is constant along the congruence, i.e. whether $u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha Q=0$. Since any geodesic can be thought of as a member of a geodesic congruence, the result for a single geodesic follows.
(Without the introduction of congruences, $\frac{x^\mu}{d\tau}$ is not a vector field, and $Q$ is not a scalar field, and the application of covariant derivatives makes no mathematical sense.)

Thanks! So the key difference between the two approaches is that the first treats Q as a function of scalar functions (i.e. components) and the second approach treats Q as an inner product of two vectors for which we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u^\mu\nabla_\mu$, right?

I think the problem lies in the notation. I guess Tong is treating the components $\xi_\mu$ as scalars for which we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u^\alpha\partial_\alpha$. And the alternative derivation thinks of the $\xi_\mu$ as the component of a covector for which we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha$.
